# Why does Amazon require lexicographically ordering query string parameters when signing requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hmac

AWS' query parameter ordering code [can be seen on their Github repository](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/auth/AbstractAWSSigner.java#L168).

I have thought about why they might require API clients to sign requests:

- intermediate proxies might canonicalize URLs and mess up the original query string order
- The [URI RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) specifies absolutely nothing about the order of the query string parameters, or that it should be preserved

My best guess is that, because of the RFC, Amazon reckoned they'd play it safe and require both sides to sign the ORDERED request.

I do, however, would like the final/official word on this. Surely the implementors had a good reason for this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The request signature ensures that the sender and receiver can agree on exactly what was sent in the request and that no intermediate parties tampered with it.

Many parts of an HTTP request can change without changing the semantics of the request. For example the HTTP headers can be re-ordered, as can the query parameters as you rightly point out.

So the request must be [canonicalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonicalization) into a form that removes these ambiguities and that both parties will use to sign the request. Otherwise each party could generate different signatures for the same request. Ordering the query parameters is just part of this process. Amazon describes their canonicalization process and their motivation [in the docs for the AWS V4 signature format](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html).